# Windows 10: How to hide window without closing?

Tags: windows, windows-10, taskbar, window-manager

Coming from a Mac OS background, I find it immensely useful to be able to have an app running, loaded in memory, and doing updates but having no visible open windows. This allows things like Facebook messenger, Mail etc. to keep updated without them being "open windows" that are still active in the foreground. It also allows you to switch to these most used apps very quickly without them loading into memory and logging in every time you want to use them.

But this seems to be impossible in Windows?

The closest thing I can find is minimize. But minimized windows still show up in the alt+tab menu and when you swipe up with 3 fingers / left edge swipe. I really want these windows to be out of sight and out of mind, but running so that I can get updates from them and so that they open quickly when I do decide to use them.

Is there a way to do this? Maybe with the help of a 3rd party tool?

Thanks

Comment: I second this, navigation and menu'ing basics are still just so janky in Windows compared to Mac OS...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You could always use **Virtual Desktop**

<kbd>Windows Key</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>

This will allow you to open virtual desktop, that way you are not so cluttered. This will also leave the application that you have opened or minimized,while you have the other desktop with the tasks a hand that will no longer bother you.

To quickly change between them you can use.

**To go to the left use.**

<kbd>Windows Key</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Left</kbd>

**To go to the Right use.**

<kbd>Windows Key</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Right</kbd>

Then you can use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> to change through the windows when on the desktop or Virtual Desktop that you selected.

This would be the best solution built into windows 10 that you could use.

**Edit:**

For a way to send it to the Tray you could always use the application listed below.

[RBtray](http://rbtray.sourceforge.net/)

I know it was used it Windows 7 May work in windows 10 although I can not test it at the moment.

The source code is open source and the program is basic.

Just start it manually or have it start up with windows by placing a shortcut in your Startup folder.

**Start up folder paths.**

**C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp**

Or Under your User name in the same path.